# DirectX10 HLSL - Converting between UV and Texel and back

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl

I'm trying to do convert between texels and uv's

I thought I could define a texel's size by doing `1/width` or `1/height`. the divide that to get the texel number.

I be wrong.

This is what I've been trying to do.

```
float4 PostPS(PostIn In) : SV_Target
{
    float4 color = 0;

    uint width, height;
    PostTex.GetDimensions(width, height);

    float2 uv = In.texCoord;
    float2 texelSize = float2(1/width, 1/height);

    // Convert coords to texels
    uint x = (uv.x / texelSize.x);
    uint y = (uv.y / texelSize.y);

    // Convert back again to uv.
    uv.x = x * texelSize.x;
    uv.y = y * texelSize.y;

    color = PostTex.Sample(pointFilter, uv);

    return color;
}
```

I realise there could be some degree of rounding errors, but I would have thought it would have worked to some degree.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared width and height as uint. 1 is int or uint, too. If you divide uint and uint, you'll get an uint. So your texelSize will always be (0, 0).

Instead of dividing by the texel size, multiply by the width and height:

```
uint x = uv.x * width;
uint y = uv.y * height;
```